# How can I find the geographical location of the browser (like Google Search)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

How does Google Search gets the details of our location (that is the name of the city and the State), when we are performing the Search Operation?

I am using Java J2EE , please tell me how to implement this type of behaviour?

Comment: Why did you tag javascript? Didn't you mean java?

Comment: If you are using J2EE why is this question tagged JavaScript and not J2EE?

Comment: I removed java script tag from this question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways

- use the ip address in the HTTP header as suggested by Quentin and then use a reverse-geocoding service (google provides one). The issue with this is that this is not exact as the user can use a privacy proxy such as TOR, be routed through a VPN, deliberately mask his IP etc
- explicitly ask the user's permission to browser geolocate. This has the implicit benefit of letting the user know that the server is geolocating. Search for 'HTML 5 geolocation' for more information on this

Comment: So will this be an replace of using ResourceBundle  ??

Comment: sorry, not sure what your talking about !